# Should I model statistical summary as a separate entity or with the summarized entity as part of the key

Tags: oracle, database-design, oracle-19c

I run several tests on each unit on a wafer and want to store a summary (median, cpk, std dev, etc) of the results for each test across the wafer.  I also want to store a summary of the results for each test for each lot, where a lot is a group of wafers.

Should I model a summary entity (identified by test number + a timestamp) that is many to many with wafers and with lots, or should I model a wafer summary with key wafer id + test number and a separate lot summary with key lot id + test number?

If there is only one wafer in a particular lot than the wafer and lot can point to the same summary with the first approach, avoiding redundancy.   The actual data is more complex, with more chances for redundancy if a wafer can be tested several times but isn't always.

Comment: Firstly, which database system and version are you using? (You should almost always tag that.) Also, please provide a little bit better detail on the `fields` involved and what a `summary` is composed of. Perhaps a View off of the main data would save you from a semi-redundant Table, but your objects / data model is not entirely clear as written.

Comment: I'm not convinced it matters, but it's Oracle, I believe 19C.  In this case the summary is a series of statistics summarizing the results of each electrical test--median, mean, cpk, std dev, iqr, 1st quartile, 3rd quartile, etc.  each wafer has many dice. each die has hundreds or thousands of tests, these statistics will be calculated for each test per wafer and also per lot, where a lot is 1-25 wafers.

Comment: Tagging the database system and version is always important because your implementation options can vary widely depending on that. E.g. the design implementation in Oracle SQL will be extremely different than in MongoDB and TimescaleDB, to name a few examples. Please also put your updates in the original Post. Specifically if you could list the objects and their properties in a table-like form, that would be easier for people to digest as opposed to reading about them. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This sound a lot like [cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLAP_cube).

In a cube, you storing each individual test (the more granular, the better) and then run all sorts of aggregations on the data. The results of aggregations are also stored and then you can slice the final results by lots, by time, by whatever else you want.